# I cannot change the privileges in phpmyadmin what can I do

Tags: phpmyadmin, privileges

So I have been trying to change my phpmyadmin privileges for while and I keep running into the error

```
#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I am trying to change these settings using the interface on phpmyadmin but the same error occurs. I can log into the server and my scripts work just fine. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

It seems something bad has happened with your root account.

You could try logging in as 'root'@'127.0.0.1' (or @'%', depending on your distribution) — it's possible that other account hasn't also been damaged in the same way. To do that, edit your phpMyAdmin configuration file, `config.inc.php`, and change the host field from 'localhost' to '127.0.0.1'. Then you can go in and edit the root@localhost user to give all the permissions.

If that doesn't work, you'll probably need to reset the permissions for your user. There's an [answer over at serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/483966/67211) that pretty clearly lists the steps:

The details you can find in the MySQL documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

1. Shutdown MySQL
2. Start MySQL with: `mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking`
3. In mysql run:

   `UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE User='root';`

   `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;`
4. Shutdown MySQL
5. Start MySQL as you usually do.

You might be able to log in through phpMyAdmin for step 3 rather than running the commands manually.

The exact SQL command to run might change depending on your MySQL/MariaDB version, please let me know which version you're running so I can adjust the command accordingly.